# IIS Domain Restriction not working

Tags: domains, iis

I need to enable Domain based restriction in IIS. Till now, I have done following

1. Enabled IP Address and Domain restrictions from Turn Windows Featured On/Off
2. In IIS -> Edit Features Settings, Access for unspecified clients set to deny and enabled domain name restrictions
3. In Add Allow entry, added entry for domain. (eg. TestingDomain.Com)

Still, I am getting 404 error.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I found out domain filtering applied on clients domain and not on request domain. Hope it may help someone